# A quote by Disraeli, can you interpret and explain its meaning?

Tags: grammar, expressions, quotes, archaicisms

> "Talk to women, talk to women as much as you can. This is the best school. This is the way to gain fluency, because **you need not care what you say**, and **had better not be sensible**. They, too, will rally you on many points, and as they are women you will not be offended. Nothing is of so much importance and of so much use to a young man entering life as to be well criticised by women."

Sensible means to be reasonable, thoughtful, cautious, practical. Or of a statement or course of action) chosen in accordance with wisdom or prudence; likely to be of benefit.

Would it mean that if acting foolish and idiotic in a thoughtful way (on purpose), you'll be able to understand the boundaries and gain the fluency required in speaking to women. In a sense, what you learn and the experiences gained from acting foolish will prove invaluable long-term.

Am I correct? Can someone pass their thoughts?

Comment: I don't think that he's recommending outright foolishness, but just advising against trying to win arguments with women (even if you ever could). (parenthetical thought added using my own experience)

Comment: Not real sure, but if you click "edit" yourself you'll see "Edited to add 1 character," which means not much was done.  There's also probably a way to see a side by side comparison of all the edits made so far, but I don't know how.  It's a bad answer, I know, but maybe just read the new version and see if it still says what you want.  sorry not much help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of **sensible** has changed over time. Here's an analysis of the title of Jane Austen's novel *Sense and Sensibility* from [schmoop.com](http://www.shmoop.com/sense-and-sensibility/title.html)

> ... the traits included in the
>   title describe these two main characters to a tee. Elinor embodies
>   "sense" completely; she's practical, intellectual, and logical in all
>   things. Her younger sister Marianne, however, is "sensibility" all the
>   way.
>
> Here, we have to remember that "sensible" didn't always mean what it
>   means to us today. We generally think of "sensibility" as basically
>   being practicality, but back in the day, it actually meant kind of the
>   opposite. In Austen's time, "sensibility" was closer to what we'd call
>   "sensitivity." Marianne is totally emotional, sensitive, and wrapped
>   up in her feelings (especially when they're romantic ones), and thus
>   is the incarnation of Austenian "sensibility." The challenge at the
>   heart of the novel is for "sense" and "sensibility" to cooperate, and
>   for the sisters to find a meeting point between reason and emotion.

So Disraeli is saying that a young man need not be *sensitive* to what women say, ie not offended or embarrassed or feel belittled.

Comment: Just to add to that, _sensible_ is a French word, and in French it retains its meaning of _sensitive_.